# vsftpd 2.2.2 - 500 OOPS: priv_sock_get_cmd

Tags: linux, centos, command-line, ftp, vsftpd

I've installed vsftpd to access the machine over ftp however I'm getting the error below:

```
>>>  USER username
<<<  331 Please specify the password.

>>>  PASS ***********
<<<  500 OOPS: cannot change directory:/home/username

  --> FTP reconnected
>>>  PWD
<<<  500 OOPS: priv_sock_get_cmd

Error EElFTPSUnacceptedReplyError: Unaccepted server reply (error code is 500)
```

I've confirmed port 21 is open.
The versions being used are vsftpd v. 2.2.2 on centos 6.8.

Comment: what are permission in `/home/username` ? have you chrooted it in `vsftpd.conf` ?